# Change citation-label to only include one to two letters per author

Tags: citations, csl

I need to finish a paper for university which has very specific citation requirements. I am using Zotero for my literature, which uses CSL to define its citation styles.

My in-text citations need to look as follows:

1. For one or more than three author(s): Author Author, Title, 1999: [Au99]
2. For two authors: Author Author, Foo Bar, Title, 1999: [AB99]
3. For three authors: Author Author, Foo Bar, Alice Bob, Title, 1999: [ABB99]

I am currently using the DIN 1505-2 (alphanumeric) style, which comes pretty close. Is there any way to adapt it to my needs? I do not understand the way these things are formatted in CSL. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Link to the style: https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/din-1505-2-alphanumeric.csl

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not at least not in an automated way. `citation-label` as used in that style is auto-generated by the CSL processor built-into Zotero and can't be customized.

What is possible is to put

`citation-label: AB99`

(and so on) into Zotero's Extra field and have that show up as the citation label. This does mean, though, that you'll have to manually add all the labels manually to the Zotero entries, so not sure if that's appealing. It's the only way to get what the required output, though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I might switch over to latex for now.